# Как указать ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE если VALUES много?

Tags: postgresql

```
INSERT INTO table1
 (id,data) 
 VALUES (1,"первый"),(2,"первый")

 ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE SET data=?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Данные `insert` в блоке `DO UPDATE` доступны через специальную псевдотаблицу `excluded`. То есть для обновления `data` конфликтующих строк можно сделать вот так:

```
INSERT INTO table1
 (id,data) 
 VALUES (1,'первый'),(2,'первый')
 ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE SET data=EXCLUDED.data;
```